# How to decrypt AES-ECB using C# with a 10 byte key

Tags: c#, encryption

There is some data encrypted by AES-ECB PKCS#5 using *[AS3Crypto](http://crypto.hurlant.com/)*.However the data has a strange key(Since the key and source data are related to confidential contents, I randomly generated another set of data and a 10-byte key).

```
Encrypted Data:1728e59d7106980478e7a48308fe15d894e0c5fd6edd72e3401ce43ea65744f5a8de13d9acf1237b76ebd31580441e24eaa499cee677d5d9d8ba7dc3465d0ff5
Source:The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Key:pKc8s0T2Mw
```

The encrypt and decrypt script:

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import com.hurlant.crypto.Crypto;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.ICipher;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.IPad;
import com.hurlant.crypto.symmetric.PKCS5;

var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray()
data.writeMultiByte("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog","UTF8")

var key:ByteArray = new ByteArray()
key.writeMultiByte("pKc8s0T2Mw","UTF8")

var cipher:ICipher
var padding:IPad = new PKCS5()
cipher = Crypto.getCipher("aes-ecb",key)
padding.setBlockSize(cipher.getBlockSize())
padding.pad(data)
cipher.encrypt(data)
trace("Length:" + data.length.toString())

var hr:String = ""
for(var p:int = 0;p < data.length;p++)
{
    if(data[p].toString(16).length == 1)
        hr = hr + "0" + data[p].toString(16)
    else
        hr = hr + data[p].toString(16)
}
      
trace(hr)   //Encrypted data in hex
      
cipher.decrypt(data)
padding.unpad(data)
trace(data.toString())  //Decrypted data
```

Now I need to implement it using C#.

```
byte[] data = HexStringToByteArray(hex);
RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
rDel.KeySize = 128;     //FIXME:How to set the key size to apply the key
rDel.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pKc8s0T2Mw");
rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor();
byte[] result = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
```

It throws an error "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm".How to make it work?

I would appreciate it if you can give me some advice.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try expanding the key to `pKc8s0T2Mw\0\0\0\0\0\0` (so considering the missing characters as 0)

Comment: The Key is not the password. AES keys can *only* be 128, 192 or 256 bits.  Either AS3Crypto breaks the standard or it pads the key to the smallest allowed size. Your key is only 80 bits (10 Latin chars * 8 bits)

Comment: Checking AS3Crypto's [code](http://crypto.hurlant.com/demo/srcview/) (the AESKey class specifically), it seems that it *doesn't* actually check the key size, resulting in invalid data. Even if you pass `aes-256`, it will ignore the size and simply use whatever key you provide. You'll just have to ensure the keys you pass to AS3Crypto have a valid length

Comment: @xanatos    Thanks.I have tried to fill the missing byte with 0.When I use my generated data,it says "padding is invalid and cannot be removed";when I use the source data ,it says "length of the data to decrypt is invalid".The length of source data is 57220 both in C# and in AS,however AS3Crypto could decrypt it correctly,C# could not.According to this, I think this problem is still related to padding or key length.

Comment: @WHC just use a valid key size with AS3Crypto.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks.I'm sure that it's the password.I decompiled the source application and got that.I separated the code and run them independently and the source data is recovered.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos    Yes I found that.But the developer has written all the things.I wonder if I can still decrypt the data using this corrupted key.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: @WHC I suspect you can't without converting all the code from the com.hurlant.crypto library to C#. It isn't so much code, so it is doable, but it is still a pain (you would have to convert the AESKey.as, the ECBMode.as and the PKCS5.as). The main difference (the "problem") is that the `BytaArray` of AS3 is auto-expanding vs the `byte[]` that isn't. You must replicate this difference in C# to replicate the buggy working of the library

Comment: @xanatos  Thanks.I finally used a irregular way (Make an external decrypt swf and use flash.external.ExternalInterface to communicate with C#) to do that.

Comment: @Artjom B Thanks.The source code was not written by me.I just want to decrypt it.